# Spreading my dataframe with multiple unique identifiers

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I'm trying to create a dataframe that spreads my dataframe from this:

`my_data1 <- data.frame(Tank = c("1A", "1D", "1F", "1A", "1F", "2A"), Bag = c("C1", "C2", "C2", "C1", "C2", "T1"), name = c("ally", "ally", "nancy", "ted", "mark", "ted"), deformity=c("spinal", "eye", "snout", "spinal", "head", "eye"))`

to this:

`my_data2 <- data.frame(Tank = c("1A", "1D", "1F", "2A"), Bag = c("C1", "C2", "C2", "T1"), ally_deformity = c("spinal", "eye", NA, NA), nancy_deformity=c(NA, NA, "snout", NA), ted_deformity=c("spinal", NA, NA, "eye"), mark_deformity=c(NA, NA, "head", NA))`

So I want the columns "Tank" and "Bag" to be my unique identifiers and every other column to be the deformities each individual person found for that specific tank and bag. I've been trying tidyr's spread with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
my_data1 %>%
  mutate(name = str_c(name, '_deformity')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = deformity)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  Tank  Bag   ally_deformity nancy_deformity ted_deformity mark_deformity
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>           <chr>         <chr>         
#1 1A    C1    spinal         NA              spinal        NA            
#2 1D    C2    eye            NA              NA            NA            
#3 1F    C2    NA             snout           NA            head          
#4 2A    T1    NA             NA              eye           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you could do:

```
reshape(my_data1, v.names = "deformity", timevar = "name", dir="wide", idvar = "Tank", sep="_")

  Tank Bag deformity_ally deformity_nancy deformity_ted deformity_mark
1   1A  C1         spinal            <NA>        spinal           <NA>
2   1D  C2            eye            <NA>          <NA>           <NA>
3   1F  C2           <NA>           snout          <NA>           head
6   2A  T1           <NA>            <NA>           eye           <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(my_data1), Tank + Bag ~ paste0(name, "_deformity"))
```

gives

```
   Tank Bag ally_deformity mark_deformity nancy_deformity ted_deformity
1:   1A  C1         spinal           <NA>            <NA>        spinal
2:   1D  C2            eye           <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
3:   1F  C2           <NA>           head           snout          <NA>
4:   2A  T1           <NA>           <NA>            <NA>           eye
```